# Употребляется ли глагол РАССЫПАЛИСЬ со сравнением КАК ПЕСОК СКВОЗЬ ПАЛЬЦЫ?

Tags: фразеология, стилистика, выбор-слов

Например: ...ветер принёс слова, и они **рассыпались**, как песок сквозь пальцы.

Или правильнее будет сказать: ...они **просыпались**, как песок сквозь пальцы.

p.s. последнее как-то не звучит...

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Ветер принёс слова, и они **просЫпались**, как песок сквозь пальцы.

Варианты такие: что-то может утекать, протекать, **сыпаться/просЫпаться** сквозь пальцы, как песок; что-то может **рассыпаться,** как песок, или **осыпаться**, как песок.

Примеры:

Деньги никогда не задерживались у Якунина, **протекали сквозь пальцы, как песок**. [Дарья Донцова. Доллары царя Гороха (2004)]

Что-то осело в памяти, **что-то утекло, как песок**, сквозь пальцы,  [Вацлав Михальский. Весна в Карфагене (2001)]

Капают по капле, шумят как дождь, рассыпаются в воздухе яркими фейерверками, душат, оглушают, **сыплются как песок сквозь пальцы**. [Мария Голованивская. В прошлом году в Марьенбаде (1990-2000)]

Но прошлое, лежащее у ног, **Просыпано сквозь пальцы**, как песок, [Игорь Сухих. Жить после Колымы // «Звезда», 2001]

Всё развалится и упразднится, и **все рассыплется, как песок.** [И. А. Ильин. Об органическом понимании государства и демократии (1950)]

Мягкая пыль дороги, еще влажная от росы, **осыпалась, как песок с колес,**  [П. С. Романов. Русь (1922)]

Answer (score 0):

(1) "Рассыпались, как песок сквозь пальцы" - неверно.
"Просыпались, как песок сквозь пальцы" - верно, но не очень подходит. "Просыпалось, как песок сквозь пальцы" обычно говорят о чем-то, что уже удалось собрать, можно и нужно было хранить, но не удалось. Хотя бы должна быть обозначена попытка их собрать/удержать.

(2)Я бы заменил "и" на "но", чтобы обозначить неожиданный поворот событий (ведь обычно слова не рассыпаются).

Поэтому советую такие варианты:

**Ветер принёс слова, но они рассыпались, как песок.**

**Ветер принёс слова, я пыталась их собрать/удержать, но они просыпались, как песок сквозь пальцы.**